# Test Flask render_template() context

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Flask route that looks like this:

```
@app.route('/')                                                                 
def home():                                                                                                                  
    return render_template(                                                     
        'home.html',                                                            
        greeting:"hello"                                       
    )
```

How do I test that the `'home.html'` template was rendered, and that the `render_template()` context defined the `greeting` variable with a particular value?

These should be (and probably are) pretty easy to test, but I'm really not sure how to do this with Flask and unittest.

Comment: Did you finally got a solution ?

Comment: I guess instead of `greeting:"hello"` you wanted to write `greeting="hello"`?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `assert_template_used` method of `TestCase` provided by [flask-testing](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing).

```
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        return myflaskapp

    def test_greeting(self):
        self.app.get('/')
        self.assert_template_used('hello.html')
        self.assert_context("greeting", "hello")
```

The method `create_app` must provide your flask app.

Comment: Works! Just had to import this way: `from flask_testing import TestCase`

Comment: [flask-testing is not maintained](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/issues/134)

Answer (score 18):

[Flask official documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/signals/) suggests that you use the [`template_rendered` signal](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.render_template) *(available since version 0.6)* for unit-testing your templates and the variables used to render it.

> For example, here is a helper context manager that can be used in a unittest to determine which templates were rendered and what variables were passed to the template:

```py
from flask import template_rendered
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def captured_templates(app):
    recorded = []
    def record(sender, template, context, **extra):
        recorded.append((template, context))
    template_rendered.connect(record, app)
    try:
        yield recorded
    finally:
        template_rendered.disconnect(record, app)
```

> This can now easily be paired with a test client:

```py
with captured_templates(app) as templates:
    rv = app.test_client().get('/')
    assert rv.status_code == 200
    assert len(templates) == 1
    template, context = templates[0]
    assert template.name == 'index.html'
    assert len(context['items']) == 10
```

Comment: The blinker library that the signals are based on didn't have any major release since 2015.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to take a look at the [Flask documentation for testing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#the-first-test).

Using the docs as a guide you should be able to set up a test case that can check the contents of the response.

```
import unittest
import yourappname

class MyAppTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = yourappname.app.test_client()

    def test_greeting(self):
        rv = self.app.get('/')
        self.assertIn('hello', rv.data)
```

where `yourappname` is the name of your app/project.

Comment: Thanks, stephenmuss. I've looked at the Flask documentation for testing and am coming up empty. Your solution tests the *response*. What I would like to test is the *request*, specifically, the values passed to `render_template()`. I can use `test_request_context()` and then access `flask.request`, but that doesn't get me any closer to testing the request as I want.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to use Jinja setup in your Html page, pass the variable to the page and see if updated.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/templating/#jinja-setup

http://jinja.pocoo.org/

As an example:

## flask template

```
@app.route('/')                                                                 
def home():                                                                                                                  
    return render_template(                                                     
        'home.html',                                                            
        greetingDictionary = {"greeting": "hello" , "forthoseabouttorock" :"wesaluteyou" }                                       
    )
```

## html page

```
{% for key in greetingDictionary %}
<h1>{{key}}</h1>
<p>{{greetingDictionary[key]}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: He means to test programmatically.

Comment: I search in google "render template context examples flask" and this was the first post to appear. This comment is the one which gives me a better clue about what was I trying to understand.

Comment: @CorinaRoca i did not understand if the answer was somehow useful or not, however good if at the end some answers here helped you.