# How to test Flask view context and templates using pytest?

Tags: flask, pytest

I'm using pytest with Flask and want to test my views and templates but I'm unclear how best to do this.

I'm aware I can test the contents of the HTML output, e.g.:

```py
def test_my_view(test_client):
    # test_client is a fixture representing app.test_client()
    response = test_client.get("/my-url")
    assert b"<h1>My page title</h1>" in response.data
```

But there are things I'm not sure how best to do:

1. How do I test which template is being used by the view?
2. How do I test the context the view sends to the template? (e.g. check that `login_form` is an instance of `LoginForm`)
3. If I want to test that a more complex HTML tag is present, say a `<form>` tag with the correct `action` attribute, is the only way to check for the presence of the entire tag (e.g. `<form method="get" class="form-lg" action="/other-url">`) even if I'm not bothered about other attributes? How could I just check for the `action`, assuming other forms are on the page too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've realised that 1 and 2 can be solved by a solution like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987564/test-flask-render-template-context), slightly altered for use with pytest.

Let's say we have this Flask view:

```py
from flask import render_template
from app import app

@app.route("/my/view")
def my_view():
    return render_template("my/template.html", greeting="Hello!")
```

We want to test that calling that URL uses the correct template, and that has the correct context data passed to it.

First, create a reusable fixture:

```py
from flask import template_rendered
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def captured_templates(app):
    recorded = []

    def record(sender, template, context, **extra):
        recorded.append((template, context))

    template_rendered.connect(record, app)
    try:
        yield recorded
    finally:
        template_rendered.disconnect(record, app)
```

I also have a `test_client` fixture for making requests in tests (something like the [`testapp` fixture in Flask Cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/tests/conftest.py) or the [`test_client` fixture in this tutorial](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/testing-a-flask-application-using-pytest/)).

Then write your test:

```py
def test_my_view(test_client, captured_templates):
    response = test_client.get("/my/view")

    assert len(captured_templates) == 1

    template, context = captured_templates[0]

    assert template.name = "my/template.html"

    assert "greeting" in context
    assert context["greeting"] == "Hello!"
```

Note that you might have more than one element in `captured_templates`, depending on what your view does.

Comment: this was awesome! exactly what I needed! good job sir!

Comment: this does not work for me, gives zero captured render templates: I made a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70824101/testing-captured-templates-in-flask-using-pytest-test-client