# Testing Flask methods which return a render_template

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I have looked into a bunch of different options, but since Python is really as dynamic as we want it to be, I wanted to ask here.

When doing unit tests, it allows me to mock data and test functionality for expected and unexpected results.  I noticed that there are a large number of functions in the app i am working on which are Flask Routes, which return render_templated data.  Not bad, I am used to that.  The issue here is that I wanted to mock data and test those endpoints.  I saw there are some options though.  When looking on github, i noticed a no-longer-maintained tool flask-testing is no longer maintained it seems. [Test Flask render_template() context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987564/test-flask-render-template-context/24914680#24914680)

I was thinking this would be useful to touch the context to see the resulting data, which is more important than the rendered template to me.  That way, I could control inputs and test the resulting dataset.

Is there something that is in unittest or other that is up to date? If this doesn't work, I guess I could just parse the HTML if i know where the data is for it, but it seems a bit bulky to me to just ensure the data passed into render_template is right or wrong.

What is the way people do this normally?   parse resulting html for the data you need, or is there a way to mock and obtain the context of the result in order to verify.  I have been looking through base docs for unittest and have yet to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I just parse the HTML. This makes sure both the data is there (and correct) and the page gets rendered correctly.

If you have a complex function, I'd just extract it out of the view function and unit test it directly.

I am not convinced that mocking would be a great idea here, so I do not mention that you could mock "render_template" itself :-)

Comment: That is something I was considering on a team refactor.  Have all the guts of the function shift into a util function and then the view just does something like: ```@app.route("/") def main(): 
results = fetchData()
return render_template("index.html", **results)```  I just wasnt sure how _right_ it was.

Comment: Def. test the fetch_data function separately. And then do one simple Integration test a la "assert some_html_output in test_client.get('/')". PS I am on mobile, so the code snippet was Out of the top of my head and possible wrong, but you get the idea.

Comment: you're good.  That sounds about like what makes sense to me.  Not sure if that is the way we are suppose to do it, but i think its how i will.  If you can tweak your answer to have a more robust answer with something akin to the example i placed, I will give you +1 and if it isnt passed up in a few days with something better, Ill give you the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help a bit :-) And well, I have nothing to add, except - get used to encounter a lot of no longer maintained Flask extensions. While the core projects (Flask, itsdangerous, Jinja2..) are very well maintained, the plugin eco system does not look too healthy.